# Object Oriented 21 card game not working?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, random

Ok, so my problem right now is that my teacher is asking us to make 3 classes. One class (PlayingCard) returns a rank and suit for each card, which I got working. The other one, deckofplayingcards, is supposed to use 2 instance variables of an array of 52 playingcard objects, and index of the top card in the deck. My constructor is giving me problems though. I pass my values back from PlayingCard as a string, and I need to declare an array of unique object cards as these strings. It is not working, to say the least. I have attached the photo of what he asks for specifically. [H.W. assignment descirption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGtcq.png)

My problem now is, that I cannot make an array of objects (in DeckOfPlayingCards at the end of the code) equal to a string (which is generated in the method finalValue in PlayingCard). Any help please? Also, any other corrections or tips for my H.W./code would be appreciated. Here is my code. It would return when working correctly something like 1 of hearts.
PlayingCard:

```
public class PlayingCard {

private String suit;
private String rank;

public String getSuit(String suitCounter){
    String newSuit = null;
    switch(suitCounter){
    case("S"):
        newSuit = "Spades";
    break;
    case("H"):
        newSuit = "Hearts";
    break;
    case("C"):
        newSuit = "Clubs";
    break;
    case("D"):
        newSuit = "Diamonds";
    break;
    }
    suit = newSuit;
    return suit;
}
public String getValue(int valueCounter){
    String newValue = null;
    switch(valueCounter){
    case(1):
        newValue = "Ace";
    break;
    case(2):
        newValue = "2";
    break;
    case(3):
        newValue = "3";
    break;
    case(4):
        newValue = "4";
    break;
    case(5):
        newValue = "5";
    break;
    case(6):
        newValue = "6";
    break;
    case(7):
        newValue = "7";
    break;
    case(8):
        newValue = "8";
    break;
    case(9):
        newValue = "9";
    break;
    case(10):
        newValue = "10";
    break;
    case(11):
        newValue = "Jack";
    break;
    case(12):
        newValue = "Queen";
    break;
    case(13):
        newValue = "King";
    }
    rank = newValue;
    return rank;
}
public String finalValue(String passedSuit, int passedValue){
    String newSuit = getSuit(passedSuit);
    String newValue = getValue(passedValue);
    return newValue + " of " + newSuit
}
}
```

DeckOfPlayingCards

```
public class DeckOfPlayingCards {
PlayingCard[] card = new PlayingCard[52];
PlayingCard cardTop = new PlayingCard();

DeckOfPlayingCards(){
    cardTop = card[0];
    String randomNumberResult=null;
    String randomNum1 = null;
    String newval=null;
    int randomNumGen1 = (int)(Math.random() * (4-1))+1;
    if(randomNumGen1==1){
        newval = "H";
    }
    else if(randomNumGen1==2){
        newval = "S";
    }
    else if(randomNumGen1==3){
        newval = "C";
    }
    else if(randomNumGen1==4){
        newval = "D";
    }
    randomNum1 = newval;
    int randomNumGen2 = (int)(Math.random() * (13-1))+1;
    int randomNum2 = randomNumGen2;
    PlayingCard finalVal = new PlayingCard();
    for(int i=0; i<card.length; i++){
        card[i] = finalVal.finalValue(randomNum1, randomNum2);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your problems begin with PlayingCard -- getter methods should not require parameters. Rather you should use true getters, and a constructor that sets the fields.

Comment: It's way more complex than it needs to be and that it should be.

Comment: I would use an enum for Suit and an enum for Rank

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be saving the 'final value' String into the array, but rather the card. Since the array is already populated with `PlayingCard`s, you should modify your method to assign the new suit/value to the fields in your class so you can call `finalValue()` whenever you need it.

I would recommend replacing your switch statements with Map implementations instead for quick access and a cleaner looking piece of code (if you haven't learned these yet, then I wouldn't recommend to put them inside a homework assignment). As @Hovercraft Full of Eels said, your code is a little complicated and should use constructors instead of mutators (setters).

Comment: I am still a little confused on what you mean. Like, I do not know how to go about doing what you are saying. Could you clarify a bit? I'm sorry I am still a beginner of sorts to java.